# Doctrine entity ManyToOne relation

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to know, what is a best to my solve my problem:

I have two entities: Cattery and Cat.
Cattery entity have two properties: Cats and Kittens. Where each property have type, for Cats Cat.type = 'Cat', Kitten.type = 'kitten'.

How to describe this relations?
Now I just use two methods, getCats(), getKittens() where with foreach method compare each cat type, and return array of cats/kittens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have three classes and tables if you think of databases

- Cittery
- Cat
- Kitten (may inherit from cat)

You Cittery class will have two methods like

```
getCats
```

and

```
getKitten
```

So you don't need to handle any type. A cittery object will hold two different arrays of cats and of kitten.